# IS NULL returning NOT NULL values

Tags: google-bigquery, isnull

I'm enriching my database with geolocation information. For management, I set up a table with all the coordinates I have in the base where 'nm_uf' (state name) is null (ie failure to enrich info), but I noticed a not feasible number of cases. I did a query and found out why: The IS NULL function is not working correctly (in my understanding).
What am I doing wrong?

[My query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7SrS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `OR` statement. Your results conform to the condition before it.
Try envelope it into additional parenthesis:

```
where (...
OR ....)
AND ...
```

Comment: Thank you. With that, I found that the problem with my code is that it only used the coordinate of the period "day" to enrich the base.